# Entity Framework code first adding extra foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I am completely new to EF Code First approach and I am facing issues regarding Migration result for one for my tables `Histories`.

I would like the `Histories` table to have a `User` foreign key (0..* relation: A user can have none or multiple histories):

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Histories = new HashSet<History>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<History> Histories { get; set; }
}

public partial class History
{
    public History()
    {
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

However this migration leads to an extra foreign key `User_Id` and whatever I try I just can't prevent it from being created.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Histories",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    UserId = c.Guid(),
                    User_Id = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.User_Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);
```

I'm using `Data Annotations` but also tried with the `OnModelCreating` method, unsuccessfully.

I read lots of posts, notably this one (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) but couldn't find a working solution.

Would someone please explain me what I am doing wrong and what I have missed ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try remove [InverseProperty("User")]. What is in the other partial class?

Comment: The model and configuration look ok. Try regenerating the migration.

Comment: @tmg: Removing the `InverseProperty` adds one more extra foreign key (there is UserId, User_Id and User_Id1).  
@Ivan: I already removed the database, deleted the `Migrations` folder and did `Add-Migration init`. Both classes actually contain much more properties, is there any chance that one of them could be involved ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was going on. The `InverseProperty` is actually needed, otherwise much more extra foreign keys are created, but the issue was due to this property in `User` other partial class:

```
public List<History> History
    {
        get
        {
            return Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.Clock).ThenBy(h => h.Type).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute did the trick and prevented the extra foreign key from being added.
I did not know that properties without `set` would be considered as columns, but seems like that's the case and caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fluent API this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<History>().HasRequired(x=> x.User).WithMany(x=> x.Histories).HasForeignKey(x=> x.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x=> x.Histories).WithRequired(x=> x.User).HasForeignKey(x=> x.UserId);
```

Property without setter has equal behavior as `[NotMapped]` attribute.